# C# blank screen when create excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel

When i click "write" button it open Excel file with workbook and writing on cells without problem. I tried on two computer which have Excel 2007 and 2013 it works correctly.

But another pc which is have Excel 2007, it just start excel only with blank screen(no worksheet) and doesnt start writing on cells.

Here is my code

```
    class CreateExcelDoc
{
    private Excel.Application app = null;
    private Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
    private Excel.Worksheet worksheet = null;
    private Excel.Range workSheet_range = null;

    public CreateExcelDoc()
    {
        createDoc();
    }
    public void createDoc()
    {
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo oldCI = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

            app = new Excel.Application();
            app.Visible = true;
            workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
            worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];          
    }
```

Comment: What version of the Excel Interop are you using (Inside References)? What culture is that machine set at? Excel Interop is only supported with "en-US"

Comment: i use version 14.0.0.0 of interopt. And machine culture which is problem is en-US.

Comment: I use 12 and I have not find a reason to go to 14...

Comment: Excel 2007 is 12.0  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel

Comment: After i added this code below solved the problem. Thanks. Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

Comment: You are welcome. I have put it as an answer. I would appreciate it if you mark the answer as solved so that the question is not left in the unanswered/unresolved queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel Interop is only supported with "en-US"

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```